# Onclick convert div to input fields and send updated value via ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

This code change the `<p>` tag into `inputfields`.

I have the data which is coming from `database` into `paragraph` tags into `tables`.

When I click on it, it changes into `inputfields`.

After I changes the value I want to update the value into  database.

For this purpose I want to send `ajax request` with those values that I changes into `inputfields`.

```js
     /**
      We're defining the event on the `body` element, 
      because we know the `body` is not going away.
      Second argument makes sure the callback only fires when 
      the `click` event happens only on elements marked as `data-editable`
    */
    $('body').on('click', '[data-editable]', function(){
      
      var $el = $(this);
                  
      var $input = $('<input/>').val( $el.text() );
      $el.replaceWith( $input );
      
      var save = function(){
        var $p = $('<p data-editable />').text( $input.val() );
        $input.replaceWith( $p );
      };
      
      /**
        We're defining the callback with `one`, because we know that
        the element will be gone just after that, and we don't want 
        any callbacks leftovers take memory. 
        Next time `p` turns into `input` this single callback 
        will be applied again.
      */
      $input.one('blur', save).focus();
      });
```

```html
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <p data-editable>First Element</p>
     <p data-editable>Second Element</p>
     <p>Not editable</p>
```

Comment: not sure what you are asking for.....

Comment: dear i have the data which is comming from database into paragraph tags into tables. when i click on it, it changes into inputfields. After i changes the value i want to update the value into  database. For this purpose i want to send ajax request with those values that i changes into inputfields.

Comment: So make an Ajax request with the value on change. What portion are you struggling with? You clearly read the value to turn it back.... so make the call there.

Comment: i want to send both elements.
please  write a example of code. How it possible?

Comment: `<p data-editable>First Element</p>
     <p data-editable>Second Element</p>`

Comment: So loop over the elements and read the text?

Comment: `$.ajax({ data: ***which variable is declared here.*** ,});`

Comment: Depends on what the server is expecting,....

Comment: Thanks dear i  got it solution according to your suggestions.